# How to alter the headers of a Request?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Is it possible to alter the headers of the [`Request`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request) object that is received by the [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchEvent) event?

Two attempts:

1. **Modify existing headers:**

   ```js
   self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
     event.request.headers.set("foo", "bar");
     event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
   });
   ```

   Fails with `Failed to execute 'set' on 'Headers': Headers are immutable`.
2. **Create new `Request` object:**

   ```js
   self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
     var req = new Request(event.request, {
       headers: { "foo": "bar" }
     });
     event.respondWith(fetch(req));
   });
   ```

   Fails with `Failed to construct 'Request': Cannot construct a Request with a Request whose mode is 'navigate' and a non-empty RequestInit.`

(See also [How to alter the headers of a Response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35421179/how-to-alter-the-headers-of-a-response))

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Creating a new request object works as long as you set all the options:

```
// request is event.request sent by browser here 
var req = new Request(request.url, {
    method: request.method,
    headers: request.headers,
    mode: 'same-origin', // need to set this properly
    credentials: request.credentials,
    redirect: 'manual'   // let browser handle redirects
});
```

You cannot use the original `mode` if it is `navigate` (that's why you were getting an exception) and you probably want to pass redirection back to browser to let it change its URL instead of letting `fetch` handle it.

Make sure you don't set body on GET requests - fetch does not like it, but browsers sometimes generate GET requests with the body when responding to redirects from POST requests. `fetch` does not like it.

Comment: Do you happen to know why a `mode` of `navigate` would be a problem?

Comment: Step 12.1 of https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-request: "If request's mode is "navigate", throw a TypeError.".

Comment: What about request body in case of post?

Answer (score 16):

You can create a new request based on the original one and override the headers:

```
new Request(originalRequest, {
  headers: {
    ...originalRequest.headers,
    foo: 'bar'
  }
})
```

See also:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request

Comment: exactly what I needed! Thanks. I was getting crazy.

Comment: You should add some context … this solution is superior. You can just throw event.request at new Request and make the immutable header "mutable" :D then you can just adjust headers on work with the newly created request. in a fetch context this is just 3 lines of code :). Also seems very robust and error proof to me.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried with a solution similar to the one in the question you mention ([How to alter the headers of a Response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35421179/how-to-alter-the-headers-of-a-response))?

In the Service Worker Cookbook, we're manually copying Request objects to store them in IndexedDB (https://serviceworke.rs/request-deferrer_service-worker_doc.html). It's for a different reason (we wanted to store them in a Cache, but we can't store POST requests because of https://github.com/slightlyoff/ServiceWorker/issues/693), but it should be applicable for what you want to do as well.

```
// Serialize is a little bit convolved due to headers is not a simple object.
function serialize(request) {
  var headers = {};
  // `for(... of ...)` is ES6 notation but current browsers supporting SW, support this
  // notation as well and this is the only way of retrieving all the headers.
  for (var entry of request.headers.entries()) {
    headers[entry[0]] = entry[1];
  }
  var serialized = {
    url: request.url,
    headers: headers,
    method: request.method,
    mode: request.mode,
    credentials: request.credentials,
    cache: request.cache,
    redirect: request.redirect,
    referrer: request.referrer
  };



  // Only if method is not `GET` or `HEAD` is the request allowed to have body.
  if (request.method !== 'GET' && request.method !== 'HEAD') {
    return request.clone().text().then(function(body) {
      serialized.body = body;
      return Promise.resolve(serialized);
    });
  }
  return Promise.resolve(serialized);
}

// Compared, deserialize is pretty simple.
function deserialize(data) {
  return Promise.resolve(new Request(data.url, data));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If future readers have a need to also *delete* keys in the immutable `Request`/`Response` headers and also want high fidelity to the immutable headers, you can effectively clone the `Header` object:

```js
const mutableHeaders = new Headers();
immutableheaders.forEach((value, key, parent) => mutableHeaders.set(key, value));

mutableHeaders.delete('content-encoding');
mutableHeaders.delete('vary');
mutableHeaders['host'] = 'example.com';
// etc.
```

You can then create a new `Request` and pass in your `mutableHeaders`.

This is preferred to the accepted answer because if you have the need to proxy a `Request`, you don't want to manually specify every possible header while including the Cloudflare, AWS, Azure, Google, etc. custom CDN headers.

---

#### Background Info

The reason why the headers are immutable or read-only in a `Request` is because:

```js
interface Request extends Body {
  readonly cache: RequestCache;
  readonly credentials: RequestCredentials;
  readonly destination: RequestDestination;
  readonly headers: Headers;
  readonly integrity: string;
    ...
```

The interface for `Headers` is:

```js
interface Headers {
    append(name: string, value: string): void;
    delete(name: string): void;
    get(name: string): string | null;
    has(name: string): boolean;
    set(name: string, value: string): void;
    forEach(callbackfn: (value: string, key: string, parent: Headers) => void, thisArg?: any): void;
}
```