# How to alter the headers of a Response?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

Is it possible to alter the headers of a [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object, as returned by [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch)?

Suppose I want to transform a response via `resFn`:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
  event.respondWith(fetch(event.request).then(resFn));
});
```

What should `resFn()` look like? One attempt:

```
function resFn(res) {
  res = res.clone();
  res.headers.set("foo", "bar");
  return res;
}
```

Fails with `TypeError: Failed to execute 'set' on 'Headers': Headers are immutable`.

(A separate question and answer explain [how to alter the headers of a request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35420980/how-to-alter-the-headers-of-a-request). Given that the the [`Request`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request) and [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) objects are surprisingly dissimilar (different properties, and their constructors take different arguments), does the same solution apply?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to alter the headers of a Request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35420980/how-to-alter-the-headers-of-a-request)

Comment: Not quite. We can change the headers of a Request. But the headers of a Response is immutable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be done by "manually" cloning the response:

```
function resFn(res) {
  return newResponse(res, function (headers) {
    headers.set("foo", "bar");
    return headers;
  });
}
```

where the `newResponse()` helper function is:

```
function newResponse(res, headerFn) {

  function cloneHeaders() {
    var headers = new Headers();
    for (var kv of res.headers.entries()) {
      headers.append(kv[0], kv[1]);
    }
    return headers;
  }

  var headers = headerFn ? headerFn(cloneHeaders()) : res.headers;

  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    return res.blob().then(function (blob) {
      resolve(new Response(blob, {
        status: res.status,
        statusText: res.statusText,
        headers: headers
      }));
    });
  });

}
```

Note that `newResponse()` returns a `Promise<Response>`.

Comment: This is amazing, nowhere else have I been able to find a solution to this. What a life saver!

Comment: god it's very complicated, i thought it's just need to do something like *res.headers.set("HeaderName", "HeaderValue")* turns out headers is immutable

Answer (score 6):

The current answer is quite verbose. You can achieve the same thing by doing the following:

```
const newHeaders = new Headers(initialResponse.headers)
newHeaders.set('foo', 'bar')
const newResponse = new Response(initialResponse.body, {
  headers: newHeaders
})
```

The initial attempt in the question was close. When you create a headers object it isn't immutable, it only becomes immutable when set on the response object.