# CacheStorage - How to retrieve the time cached of a request

Tags: javascript, caching

I'm using the JS CacheStorage API, I need to make sure that the cached request is up to date. How can I retrieve the cached time of the saved cache?

Answer (score 2):

In your cache object, you can simply store the Date.now.

Note: I would post it as a comment but I don't have the reputation for that.

Comment: it's still not clear how to add data to response when It cached

Comment: To add data to a response before caching, you must reconstruct the response as seen in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35421180/5500690

Answer (score 0):

I cache the entire app all at once whenever a semver version changes.  At the end of the caching sequence, this code fires to create a request for `/time-cached` which I present on my dashboard for debugging purposes.

```
const cache = await caches.open(theVersion);
await cache.put('/time-cached', new Response( new Date() ));
```