# Javascript - Service Workers not working correctly

Tags: javascript, python, html, caching, service-worker

I am using service workers to create an offline page for my website.

At the moment I am saving `offline.html` into cache so that the browser can show this file if there is no interent connection.

In the `fetch` event of my service worker I attempt to load `index.html`, and if this fails (no internet connection) I load `offline.html` from cache.

However, whenever I check offline mode in developer tools and refresh the page `index.html` still shows...

The request isn't failing, and it looks like `index.html` is being cached even though I didn't specify it to be.

Here is my HTML for `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Service Workers - Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Online page! </h1>
    <h3> You are connected to the internet. </h3>
</body>
<script>

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator)
{
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');
}
</script>

</html>
```

Here is my HTML for `offline.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>You are Offline - Service Workers - Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Welcome to the Offline Page!</h1>
    <h2> You are not connected to the internet but you can still do certain things offline. </h2>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is my javascript for `service-worker.js`:

```
const PRECACHE = "version1"
const CACHED = ["offline.html"];

// Caches "offline.html" incase there is no internet
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
    console.log("[Service Worker] Installed");
    caches.delete(PRECACHE)
    event.waitUntil (
        caches.open(PRECACHE)
            .then(cache => cache.addAll(CACHED))
            .then(    _ => self.skipWaiting())
    );
});

// Clears any caches that do not match this version
self.addEventListener("activate", event => {
    event.waitUntil (
        caches.keys()
            .then(keys => {
                return Promise.all (
                    keys.filter(key => {
                        return !key.startsWith(PRECACHE);
                    })
                    .map(key => {
                        return caches.delete(key);
                    })
                );
            })
            .then(() => {
                console.log('[Service Worker] Cleared Old Cache');
            })
    );
});

this.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    if (event.request.method !== 'GET') return;

    console.log("[Service Worker] Handling Request ");

    // If the request to `index.html` works it shows it, but if it fails it shows the cached version of `offline.html`

    // This isn't working because `fetch` doesn't fail when there is no internet for some reason...

    event.respondWith (
        fetch(event.request)
            .then(response => {
                console.log("[Service Worker] Served from NETWORK");
                return response;
            }, () => {
                console.log("[Service Worker] Served from CACHE");
                return catches.match(event.request.url + OFFLINE_URL);
            })
    );
});
```

I am running a server using python's simple http server like so:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Does anyone know why the offline page isn't working and how I can fix this?

Thanks for the help,
David

**EDIT:**

These images are showing that `index.html` (localhost) is still loading without internet which means it must be cached.

[image: Offline checkbox is ticked]

[image: localhost status:200 (from ServiceWorker) | service-worker.js status:failed]

**Edit 2:**

I've tried to add `no-cache` to the fetch of `index.html` and it still is fetching `index.html` when I have offline checked.

```
fetch(event.request, {cache: "no-cache"}) ...
```

Comment: Is the worker throwing any warnings and/or errors? Is it installed? Can you see the cache in dev tools? under the application tab?

Comment: @Schrodinger'scat The service worker is installed and I refreshed the page again to make sure the service worker handled the fetch of the page. In the cache there was `index.html` even though I didn't cache it.

Comment: Ok! Among other things to look for, you have typos it is `caches.match` on the fetch event and not `catches`. 

Also, If you have an `update on reload` checked, uncheck it, as when you go offline, the browser searches for a new service worker and the request fails..

Comment: @Schrodinger'scat I've fixed all my typos but that didn't fix it. When I refresh the page it loads `index.html` which means that page must be cached even when I didn't include it in my cache list `CACHED`

Comment: It looks like the index.html is served from disk cache and bypasses the service worker for some reason - noticed this after trying this out on my machine - This can be circumvented by checking `disable cache`, but that is a hack

Comment: @Schrodinger'scat Yeah, that obviously isn't the best solution but I don't see how other websites have built offline versions without having this issue. I guess my best solution would be to handle an `offline event` in `index.html` and redirect to `offline.html`. The only thing I don't like about this is it will show `/offline.html` in the browser. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think we have all forgotten how the network request works from a browser's point of view.

The issue here is, `index.html` is served from the disk cache when the service worker intercepts requests.
**browser** ===> **Service Worker** ===>**fetch event**

> inside the fetch event, we have ,
>
> - Check If there is network connectivity
>
>   - If there is, fetch from network and respond
>   - Else, fetch from cache and respond

Now, how does

> If there is network connectivity, fetch from network work?

**Service Worker OnFetch** ===> **Check in Disk Cache** ===>**Nothing? Fetch Online**

The page being fetched here, is `index.html`

and the `cache-control` headers for `index.html` ,

**Do Not** Specify a `no-cache`

Hence the whole issue of the offline page not showing up.

#### Solution

- Set a `cache-control` header with limiting values for `index.html` - On the server side
- Or, add headers in the fetch request to the effect

  - `pragma:no-cache`
  - `cache-control:no-cache`

#### How Do I add these headers to fetch?

Apparently, fetch and the browser have their own reservations about the request body when it comes to a GET

Also, weirdness and utter chaos happens If you reuse the `event.request` object, for a fetch request, and add custom headers.
The chaos is a list of `Uncaught Exceptions` due to the `fetch` event's `request.mode` attribute , which bars you from adding custom headers to a fetch when under a no-cors or a navigate mode.

Our goal is to :

**Identify** that the browser is truly **offline** and then serve a page that says so

Here's How:

> Check If you can fetch a dummy html page say `test-connectivity.html` under your origin, with a custom `cache: no-cache` header. If you can, proceed, else throw the offline page

```
self.addEventListener( 'fetch', ( event ) => {
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append( 'cache-control', 'no-cache' );
headers.append( 'pragma', 'no-cache' );
var req = new Request( 'test-connectivity.html', {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'same-origin',
    headers: headers,
    redirect: 'manual' // let browser handle redirects
} );
event.respondWith( fetch( req, {
        cache: 'no-store'
    } )
    .then( function ( response ) {
        return fetch( event.request )
    } )
    .catch( function ( err ) {
        return new Response( '<div><h2>Uh oh that did not work</h2></div>', {
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'text/html'
            }
        } )
    } ) )
} );
```

The `{cache:'no-store'}` object as the second parameter to `fetch` , is an unfortunate **NO-OP**. Just doesn't work.
Just keep it for the sake of a future scenario. It is **really** optional as of today.

If that worked, then you do not need to build a whole new `Request` object for `fetch`

cheers!

> The code piece that creates a new request is generously borrowed from 
>   @pirxpilot 's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35420980/how-to-alter-the-headers-of-a-request)

#### The offline worker for this specific question on pastebin

https://pastebin.com/sNCutAw7

Comment: Thanks I'll try this as soon as I get a chance. I thought `cache: "no-cache"` would be enough

Comment: When I go offline it says `This site cannot be reached` and there is a warning in the console: `The FetchEvent for "http://localhost:8000/" resulted in a network error response: an object that was not a Response was passed to respondWith().`

Comment: Are you using a `return` value from `then` at all times when you `fetch` or `catch` a`fetch` error?

Comment: Yes, I am. -----

Comment: Hmmm I posted my working file in the answer .Maybe you can copy that over and change as needed?

Comment: Ok, I'll try that.

Comment: Awesome, it works thanks a lot for the help! Much appreciated. I'll have to check what I did wrong in my code, probably a typo or something again.

Answer (score 2):

David, you have two errors in one line.

Your line

```
return catches.match(event.request.url + OFFLINE_URL);
```

should be

```
return caches.match('offline.html');
```

It's `catches` and you haven't defined `OFFLINE_URL` and you don't need event request url

Comment: Oh wow! I used to have `OFFLINE_URL` until I changed it into an array called `CACHED`. Shouldn't I see an error though with the typo... I'll try that now, Thank you.

Comment: I've updated my code, but it still isn't working. For some reason `index.html` is being cached even though I didn't cache it, therefore there is no error and is still showing `index.html` when there is no internet connection.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code and I got the same result as you in the dev tools network tab. The network tab says it loaded the index.html from service-worker, but actually the service-worker returns the cached Offline Page as expected!

[image: Offline Page is shown]

Comment: This is making no sense as it just started working and I haven't changed anything. I am so confused. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What happens if you uncheck `disable cache` and go offline?

Comment: @Schrodinger'scat `disable cache` is unchecked for me already. For some reason it stopped working again and I've pushed it to  http://dcallanan.github.io/service-workers/example1/ Could you tell me if it is working for you? Thanks

Comment: NP! I actually copied over your service worker already, looking now for browser weirdness if any

Comment: The behaviour is , on first load, it registers, activates, and caches `offline.html`

Then once the service worker is controlling the page, if you go offline, a normal reload is doing absolutely **Nothing** to fetch events

Whereas, If you `Clean Reload`, the browser then **for realsies** goes offline. Post which, you reload normally, and the offline page loads

Either you `clean reload` and then reload for it to work, or , you `disable cache` and reload for it to work. - **This is weird** considering, I also set the headers for the worker to a `no-store private must-revalidate no-cache`

Comment: What do you mean by a `Clean Reload`?

Comment: `cmd+shift+R` - clean reload - bypasses disk cache

Comment: Clean reload is now showing the google chrome `there is no internet connection` page. If I try clean reload when `offline` isn't checked, then the next time I check `offline` it still shows the online page.