# Service Worker: Append header to requests for CSS & JS files

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker

I've been trying to use service workers for (what seems like hours & hours), to attach a simple header to all requests. Whats frustrating is, it sort of works.

Attempt 1:

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", event => {
   const modifiedHeaders = new Headers({
      ...event.request.headers,
      'API-Key': '000000000000000000001'
   });
   const modifiedRequest = new Request(event.request, {
      headers: modifiedHeaders,
   }); 
   event.respondWith((async () => {
     return fetch(modifiedRequest);
   })());
});
```

The above code works for HTML files however for CSS & JS files I get the follow error

> ReferenceError: headers is not defined

If I disable the header requirement the page loads with images and javascript and I can interact with it like normal.

Attempt 2:

```
var req = new Request(event.request.url, {
   headers: {
     ...event.request.headers,
      'API-Key': '000000000000000000001'
      },
   method: event.request.method,
   mode:  event.request.mode,
   credentials: event.request.credentials,
   redirect: event.request.redirect,
   referrer: event.request.referrer,
   referrerPolicy: event.request.referrerPolicy,
   bodyUsed: event.request.bodyUsed,
   cache: event.request.cache,
   destination: event.request.destination,
   integrity: event.request.integrity,
   isHistoryNavigation: event.request.isHistoryNavigation,
   keepalive:  event.request.keepalive
 });
```

This attempt, I simply built a new request, which successfully included the new header on CSS & JS file requests. However, When I do a POST or redirect, things stop working and behave strange.

What is the correct approach for this? I feel that attempt 1 is the better path, but I can't seem to create the Headers object on the request no matter what I do.

The version of chrome I am using is

> Version 78.0.3904.70 (Official Build) (64-bit)

The site is an internal developer tool so cross browser compatibility isn't required. So I'm happy to load any additional libs / enable experimental features etc.

Comment: Hi Jamie, did you go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35420980/how-to-alter-the-headers-of-a-request/35421644 ?

Comment: Also this: https://www.linkedin.com/learning/vanilla-javascript-service-workers/synthesize-a-response?autoplay=true

Answer (score 4):

### The problem is that your modified requests reuse the `mode` of the original request in both of your attempts

For embedded resources where the request is initiated from markup (unless the crossorigin attribute is present) the request is in most cases made using the **`no-cors` mode which only allows a very limited specific set of simple headers**.

> no-cors — Prevents the method from being anything other than HEAD, GET
>   or POST, and the headers from being anything other than simple
>   headers. If any ServiceWorkers intercept these requests, they may not
>   add or override any headers except for those that are simple headers...

Source and more info on request modes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode

Simple headers are the following ones:  `accept` (only some values), `accept-language`, `content-language` (only some values), `content-type`.

Source: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#simple-header:

### Solution:

You need to make sure to set the mode to something other than `no-cors` when creating the modified request. You can pick either `cors` or `same-origin`, depending on whether you want to allow cross-origin requests. (The `navigate` mode is reserved for navigation only and it is not possible to create a request with that mode.)

### Why your code worked for HTML files:

The request issued when navigating to a new page uses the `navigate` mode. Chrome does not allow creating requests with this mode using the `new Request()` constructor, but seems to automatically silently use the `same-origin` mode when an existing request with the `navigate` mode is passed to the constructor as a parameter. This means that your first (HTML load) modified request had `same-origin` mode, while the CSS and JS load requests had the `no-cors` mode.

---

### Working example:

```
'use strict';

/* Auxiliary function to log info about requests to the console */
function logRequest(message, req) {
  const headersString = [...req.headers].reduce((outputString, val) => `${outputString}\n${val[0]}: ${val[1]}`, 'Headers:');
  console.log(`${message}\nRequest: ${req.url}\nMode: ${req.mode}\n${headersString}\n\n`);
}


self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  logRequest('Fetch event detected', event.request);

  const modifiedHeaders = new Headers(event.request.headers);
  modifiedHeaders.append('API-Key', '000000000000000000001');

  const modifiedRequestInit = { headers: modifiedHeaders, mode: 'same-origin' };
  const modifiedRequest = new Request(event.request, modifiedRequestInit);

  logRequest('Modified request', modifiedRequest);

  event.respondWith((async () => fetch(modifiedRequest))());
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I would try this:

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", event => {
    const modifiedRequest = new Request(event.request, {
        headers: {
            'API-Key': '000000000000000000001'
        },
    }); 
    event.respondWith((async () => {
        return fetch(modifiedRequest);
    })());
});
```

Comment: I would no longer have my original headers, instead of appending my API key. This answer is not helpful.

Comment: Haven't tried it, but the documentation says that the headers are added to the request. Have you tried it already? Does it replace the headers from the original request or does this constructor call uses the headers from the previous request and adds the new headers to it? The only reason why you see errors is a problem with the headers. Did you already check the headers of the final request (modifiedRequest)?