# How to cancel/modify/alter/replace a request in respondWith?

Tags: service-worker, workbox, request-cancelling

I'm using a workbox and trying to cache requests something like this:

```
this.serviceWorker.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
const request = event.request;
event.respondWith(
      caches.open('cache name')
         .then(cache => cache.match(request))
         .then(async (cachedResponse) => {
            // todo something
```

How Can I cancel event.request and send my custom request?
Thanks for any helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may alter or completely change the out-going request like so:

```
this.serviceWorker.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  const request = event.request;
  return event.respondWith(
    caches.open('cache name')
      .then(cache => cache.match(request))
      .then(async (cachedResponse) => {
        // create a new request, fetchi it, and return the result
        return fetch(new Request(request.url ....))
       })
```

Pay attention to the return statement I added to the third line of code :)

More info about constructing the new request: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35421858/5038943