# How to change relative paths to point to server instead of localhost?

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2, vue-resource

I'm working on a Vue app. I have a scenario where I have to call a service with Authorization header information and what I get back is HTML (an entire page with pre-rendered charts) that I have to display in a component.

The problem is, the HTML from the response has a bunch of relative paths for CSS, JS and image files. When I bind the HTML to my component, it is taking the relative path of my localhost instead of the server where this is coming from. Therefore, it cannot locate the necessary files to load.

If I enter the same URL endpoint and pass the Authorization header information from Chrome using the mod-header extension, I am able to see the rendered page.

I have tried using v-html and iframes to render the HTML, but it didn't work. Also tried passing the Host as header information. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try to intercept HTTP requests using a service worker 
https://livebook.manning.com/book/progressive-web-apps/chapter-4/23

Also this is related: [how-to-alter-the-headers-of-a-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35420980/how-to-alter-the-headers-of-a-request/35421644)